# Yabble - accessing functions loaded by yabble

Tags: javascript

Am having a problem with Yabble that I have not been able to solve.

From within my main html I load all of my js using yabble

```
<script>
require.setModuleRoot('./javascript/');
require.run('main')
</script>
```

I have a bunch of js (gamejs related). In one file I have function changeSimulationSettings(). Later within the same page I want to take user input and access the gamejs objects and change their state. The problem I am having is that I am unable to call changeSimulationSettings. It is not defined within the current context. Yabble does so much magic I am unable to find where it is defined or how to access.

```
<div>
<button type="button" onclick="updateSettings()">Update-Settings</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateSettings(){
        // access function defined in a js loaded by yabble 
        i.e. changeSimulationSettings()
}
</script>
```

All of the js is definitely being loaded as I have got functions calling each other from different files which does work. However, I am unable to call anything from js embedded within the entry web page.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this one for hours and hours.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Code defined in modules is isolated and not available globally.

I would do it the other way around: from within a module attach an event handler. Do not use "onclick=" but instead in a module, where you have `changeSimuSettings` available, do something like this (e.g. using jquery or plain DOM):

```
$('button').click(changeSimulationSettings)
```

This is cleaner and you are not leaking globals. If you insist on doing it your way, you could export `changeSimulationSettings` to global and use the code you already have. Like so (I would not recommend that):

```
window.changeSimulationSettings = function() {...
```